# Making a public setter method private in a subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In order to turn a setter that ActiveRecord generates for you, the following pattern can be used:

```
class ParentModel
  def name=(name)
    @attributes ||= {}
    @attributes[:name] = name
  end
end

class ChildModel < ParentModel

   private

   def name=(name)
     super
   end
end
```

While this works, it comes with several problems:

- Rubocop linter mark this as `Lint/UselessMethodDefinition`. This may be a false positive or bug in Rubocop. It has a good point.
- It does not turn all the other magic that ActiveRecord offers private. e.g. `attributes[:name] = foo` will still work, as will `update_attributes(name: 'foo')` and so on. I'm not looking for something entirely foolproof, just to tell the users of this class to best not use this.

Is there a more appropriate to disallow the outside world to set an attribute in Rails' ActiveRecord?

Using `private :name=` does work in above example, but not in ActiveRecord: it throws a `undefined method name= for class #<Class:...>`

Note that setting private is not the same as using [readonly_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-readonly_attributes) as that disallows both external and self to update the attribute. I want to allow self to update it, just disallow other classes to update it. It may be that this is because I misuse or misunderstand `readonly_attributes` though.

Comment: To avoid Rubocop Linter, you can write it as `class ChildModel < ParentModel; private :name=; end`

Comment: Even if a method is private, they can still be called with Object#send. Private methods are a useful convention, but they aren't guarantees in Ruby.

Comment: @Alex: strange enough, not in ActiveRecord. I presume the dark magick of "method-missing" is causing this, but that throws `undefined method 'name=' for class `#<Class:...>'`

Comment: Did you write the method name as a symbol? `private :name=` ?

Comment: @AlexHolubenko yes. And also as string. The method is weird though: `for class #<Class` hints at it looking for that method on class-method level.

Comment: @berkes ActiveRecord::Attributes does not have a private option at all for attributes and while it could have been nice as a convention YAGNI. If you don't want an attribute to be settable then don't whitelist that attribute - problem solved. It also does not use method_missing. It actually does introspection from the schema and generates setters/getters on the fly.